# How to open multiple windows with Processing?

Tags: java, image, swing, processing

I'm trying to create two windows with Processing.  Before you mark this as a duplicate, as there are other questions similar to this, I have a specific error and I can't find a solution.  When I try to `add(s)` I get the error `The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (evolution_simulator.SecondApplet)`

I'm not sure how to fix this, and any help would be appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

PFrame f;

void setup() {
    size(320, 240);
    f = new PFrame();
}

void draw() {

}

public class PFrame extends JFrame {

    SecondApplet s;

    public PFrame() {
        setBounds(100,100,400,300);
        s = new SecondApplet();
        add(s);  // error occurs here
        s.init();
        show();
    }
}

public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

    public void setup() {
        size(400, 300);
        noLoop();
    }

    public void draw() {

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry this code came from pre_dinosaurus edges

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create more than one window of a single sketch in Processing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798606/how-to-create-more-than-one-window-of-a-single-sketch-in-processing)

Comment: The error you're getting, and the solution to that error, is the exact same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798606/how-to-create-more-than-one-window-of-a-single-sketch-in-processing/32798761#32798761). In fact I'm just going to copy-paste my answer from there to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error message is because the `add()` function is expecting a `Component`, and `PApplet` is not a `Component`. This is because `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet` as of Processing 3, so old code that uses it as a `Component` will no longer work.

Instead, you can create a class that extends `PApplet` for your second window, and then call `PApplet.runSketch()` using that second `PApplet` as a parameter:

```
void setup() {
  size(100, 100);

  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
  SecondApplet sa = new SecondApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(50, 50, 10, 10);
}     

public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 100);
  }
  public void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(0);
    ellipse(100, 50, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi it's work great ! But i am trying to redraw my SecondApplet when I click on the first Window, I got the global : SecondApplet sa; and in my setup I do : sa = new SecondApplet();         Finally I am trying this : void mouseClicked() {
  print("clicked");
  sa.background(0, 0, 255);
  sa.fill(100);
  sa.redraw();
}    but it's actually changing nothing in my SecondApplet, do you know why ?

Comment: @LoganGallois If you have a follow-up question, you'll have better luck if you post it in its own question.

Comment: Okay ;) I'll post a question then ;)