# how to play videos in two windows by using just one single sketch in Processing

Tags: processing, video-processing, serial-communication

I want to play videos in two windows by using just one single sketch in Processing.
And I also want to use serial communication..
serial communication does well but a video doesn't work.
I guess the program can't find where video is.

I've searched more than one window of a single sketch in Processing.
I referred to this.
[How to create more than one window of a single sketch in Processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798606/how-to-create-more-than-one-window-of-a-single-sketch-in-processing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is the codes that I wrote.

I hope you help me please

---

### Code

```java
import processing.video.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port

Movie mov;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);

  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};


 SecondApplet sa = new SecondApplet();
  ThirdApplet na = new ThirdApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
  PApplet.runSketch(args, na);

  String portName = Serial.list()[1];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);

  sa.mov = new Movie(this, "transit.mov");
  sa.mov.loop();

}




void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(50, 50, 10, 10);

  if (myPort.available() > 0) {
    if ( (val = myPort.readStringUntil(ENTER)) != null )  val = trim(val);
    else return;
    if (val != null) {
      println(val);
    }
    }

}     

public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {
public Movie mov;

  public void settings() {
    size(500, 500);
  }


  public void draw() {

    fill(0);
    ellipse(100, 50, 10, 10);

  if ("3Low".equals(val)) {
    fill(255,random(255),200);
      ellipse(60,20,100,100);
    }

    sa.image(sa.mov,0,0);

  }
}



public class ThirdApplet extends PApplet {


  public void settings() {
    size(500, 500);
  }

  public void draw() {

    fill(0);
    ellipse(100, 50, 10, 10);

  if ("3Low".equals(val)) {
    fill(255,random(255),200);
      ellipse(60,20,100,100);
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess the program can't find where video is.

Please be more specific. What exact error message do you see? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

> I want to play videos in two windows by using just one single sketch in Processing.

The code you posted uses **three** different sketches, and you're doing weird things with the scope of each. Just write each sketch as if they were completely separate, and then add the linking code last.

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use two different sketches to play two different movies. It might look something like this:

```java
Movie movieOne;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);

  movieOne = new Movie(this, "MovieOne.mov");
  movieOne.loop();

  String[] args = {"SecondSketch"};
  SecondSketch sa = new SecondSketch();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
}

void draw() {
  image(movieOne, 0, 0);
}     

public class SecondSketch extends PApplet {
  Movie movieTwo;

  public void settings() {
    size(500, 500);
    movieTwo = new Movie(this, "MovieTwo.mov");
    movieTwo.loop();
  }

  public void draw() {
    image(movieTwo, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Please note that this is just example code, and I haven't even tried to compile it. You'll probably have to change a few things to get it working, but this should give you a general idea of the approach to take.

A simpler option might be to create two buffers using the `createGraphics()` function. Draw a movie to each buffer, and then draw the buffers to the screen.

```java
Movie movieOne;
Movie movieTwo;

PGraphics bufferOne;
PGraphics bufferTwo;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);

  bufferOne = createGraphics(500, 500);
  bufferTwo = createGraphics(500, 500);

  movieOne = new Movie(this, "MovieOne.mov");
  movieOne.loop();

  movieTwo = new Movie(this, "MovieTwo.mov");
  movieTwo.loop();
}

void draw() {
  bufferOne.beginDraw();
  bufferOne.image(movieOne, 0, 0);
  bufferOne.endDraw();

  bufferTwo.beginDraw();
  bufferTwo.image(movieTwo, 0, 0);
  bufferTwo.endDraw();

  image(bufferOne, 0, 0);
  image(bufferTwo, 500, 0);
}
```

Again, this is just example code that you might have to modify to get working perfectly.

More info can be found in [the refrence](https://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html).

If you still can't get it working, please post an updated [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question, and we'll go from there.